# Is the following methodology to find the error metrics between the two curves technically sound?

Tags: error, model-comparison, rms

I am comparing two curves, one of which is derived from physical experiment, while the latter is obtained from a simulation. The experimental curve was used to calibrate the simulation results. The points are not generated at the same intervals and the number of data points are not similar.

To compare both the curves, I am first fitting the curves using nonlinear fit with R-square=0.99 and 0.97 respectively.

[image]

Next, I am calculating the RMSE, R-square between the fitted curves (blue and red).

This comes out to be:

[image]

Can it be said that the simulation and experiment are well correlated and thus have low error?

Comment: Sure, you can say they are well correlated.  But you cannot infer the error is low: *any* simulation whose value increases with the independent variable will have a high positive correlation with the experiment.  Moreover, because one curve is derived from the other, you can't treat them as independent.  What you need here is a meaningful way, for your application, to quantify the differences between the curves.  We can't do any more than guess--so why don't you explain what the experiment is measuring and what your objective is?

Comment: @whuber The experiment is a stress strain curve for compression experiment. The simulation is a finite element simulation to calibrate the parameters for the material model.